# Show that the ideal $ I = <3 , X^3 - X^2 + 2X + 1> $ is not principal in $Z[X]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

How can i prove that

1) $I$ is not principal
2) $Z[x] / I $ is not a whole ring.

I tried the following : $<3,X^3-X^2+2X+1>  =  <X^2(X-1) + 2(X-1),3>   = <X-1,X^2+2,3>$
 I'm trying somehow to prove that $1$ cannot be generated so $I$ cannot be generated by one element.

Can someone give me some insights? ( would need some for both questions)

Comment: How many integer polynomials are there that have 3 as a multiple?

Comment: Assume I is generated principally. i.e. $I=(a(x))$ for some polynomial $a(x)$. Then try to prove contradiction.

Comment: By proving that $1 \notin I$ you would only prove that $I$ is a *proper* ideal, i.e. that $I \subsetneq \Bbb{Z}[X]$. As thedilated mentioned, $I$ being principal means that $I$ can be generated by just one element of $\Bbb{Z}[X]$.

Comment: Use \langle \rangle to produce $\langle X\rangle$ rather than $<X>$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume that $$<3,X^3-X^2+2X+1>=<p(x)>$$ for  $p(x) \in Z[x]$

So$$<3,X^3-X^2+2X+1>=p(x)Z[x]$$

Since $3\in p(x)Z[x]$ $$3=p(x)q(x) $$ where $q(x)\in Z[x]$

Which implies $p(x)=-3,-1,1$ or $3$. Since this is a contradiction $$<3,X^3-X^2+2X+1>\ne<p(x)>$$ for any $p(x)\in Z[x]$

Answer (score 0):

First show 2): $\mathbb Z[X]/(3,X^3-X^2+X+1) = \mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z[X]/(X^3-X^2+2X+1)$. Note that modulo $3$, we have
$$X^3-X^2+2X+1=X^3-X^2-(X-1)=(X-1)(X^2-1)=(X-1)^2(X+1),$$
thus the quotient is not an integral domain, because the polynomial is not irreducible.

1) follows from 2): If the ideal would be principal, it would be generated by the gcd of the two elements. But the gcd is $1$ and the computation in 2) in particular proofs that ideal is not equal to the whole ring.